# Unknown pseudo selector 'export' in WebStorm

Tags: sass, webstorm, create-react-app

I'm developing a standard `create-react-app`-based webapp using WebStorm as an IDE. For this code:

```css
$colors: ( 'primary': #000, 'error': #acda5a);
:export {
  @each $key,
  $value in $colors {
    #{unquote($key)}: $value;
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error `Unknown pseudo selector 'export'` -- any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exporting sass variables with the webpack `:export` directive is not yet supported, please follow [WEB-41662](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41662) for updates